# can we place proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For after proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a nginx as a reverse proxy in a containerised application. I have an issues in which when I add `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;` my deployment does not work.

here is the part of location block in my `nginx.conf` file.

```
location @app {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
```

but when i replace `$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for` with `http_x_forwarded_for` the deployment works but i am unable to pass the real client ip.

Can anyone please confirm if this is syntactically correct & we can add `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;` after **proxy_pass**?

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

is correct.

I have a running location block:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3333;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header x-real-ip $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
}
```

Comment: hi, i am using it in `location @app` block, do you think that can make a difference?